# swift UITextView setContentOffset works on didappear and not on willappear

Tags: swift, uitextview, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I'm trying to automatically scroll my textview at the top before the view loads, so that you can't see it actually moving upward...

i'm trying doing so with

```
var zeroOffset = CGPoint.zeroPoint
    textSpace.setContentOffset(zeroOffset, animated: false)
```

where textSpace is my UITextView.

when i place this code inside viewDidAppear it works, but the problem is that obviously you can see for a second the text scrolling, and it does't work at all when i place it inside viewWillAppear (viewDidLoad neither if can be of help).
I guess has something to do with the CGPoint that needs the view to be there before calculate the actual point but i'm not sure, is there a solution to this? thanks

Comment: How about putting it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 4):

In the viewController lifecycle, between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, there is a call `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  It is called after the subviews have been laid out.  At that point, you will have everything you need for your call to work, but it will still be before the view appears.  So override `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and place your call there.

Comment: awesome. thanks, that works perfect for setting scrollview offsets before they appear :)